# How to get each checkbox textfield value

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, struts, displaytag

**addBook.jsp**

```
<display:table name="books" excludedParams="*" pagesize="25" class="table" export="false"  sort="external" id="book" requestURI="">              
 <display:column title="#">
   <input type="checkbox" name="book" value="${book.Id}"/>
 </display:column>                    
 <display:column title="bookName" style="width: 100%" >
   <c:out value="${book.name}"/>
 </display:column>
 <display:column title="bookDiscount" style="width: 100%" >
   <html:text property="discount"styleId="discount"/>                 
 </display:column>
</display:table>
```

**bookAction.java**

```
String[] percentage = request.getParameterValues("discount");
String[] cardTypeId = request.getParameterValues("book");
```

If I check  a checkbox , I want to get that checked checkbox discount value using java in action class, so i can add the value in database. I have tried but not working. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to fetch the id of the check box na.Now compare the all id's of book with the check box id and find the position.Now the discount will be percentage[position]

ex:

```
<input id="${book.Id}" type="checkbox" name="book" value="${book.Id}"/>
```

in javascript

```
<script>
 var id = event.target.id;
 var position;
 var length = percentage.length();
 for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
   if( id == cardTypeId[i]){
    position = i;
    break;
   }
 }
 var percen = percentage[position];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your checkbox, should be part of a `Form`. And then in your `Action` class, you need to fetch the checkbox values using the `Form` attributes.

Comment: I able to fetch the checkbox value , but how i to get discount value for the book that i checked?